# Android Button background color not changing, CHANGE IN CODE, BUT NOT DISPLAYED

Tags: java, android, xml

Android Button background color not changing, CHANGE IN CODE, BUT NOT DISPLAYED
I have been using button inside the grid layout.
When I am changing the color of the button, its showing the change in the code ,but the color change is not displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udrHq.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="161dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="347dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="GO"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="30s"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="31+7"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_height="583dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timerTextView">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="518dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/* 
                      THE COLOR CHANGED IS NOT DISPLAYED */
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="14"
            android:textColor="#263238"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You're overwriting it with a tint.  That's why it isn't displayed.  Remove the tint and it will be red.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but you'd need to describe what you actually want to happen for us to help.

Comment: I am using a button inside the grid layout, and for that button i am changing the color but when i am previewing the app, its showing the default color

Comment: You should remove the attribute `android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"` from `button2`

Answer (score 0):

Try it without this

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
```